# custom exception in Ktor type safe route serialization failure

Tags: kotlin, ktor

```kotlin
@Resource("/articles/{version}")
data class Articles(val version: @Contextual ApiVersion)

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080) {
        // plugins
        install(Resources) {
            serializersModule = SerializersModule { contextual(ApiVersion::class, ApiVersionSerializer) }
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) { json() }
        install(StatusPages) {
            exception<InvalidApiVersion> { call, cause ->
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, cause.message)
            }
        }

        // Routes
        routing {
            get<Articles> { article ->
                call.respondText("articles version ${article.version}")
            }
        }
    }.start(true)
}
```

I have a single route `/article/${version}` and the version is typed `enum class ApiVersion`, for that I have a custom serializer.

```kotlin
internal data class InvalidApiVersion(override val message: String) : Exception(message)

enum class ApiVersion(val version: String) {
    VERSION_1_0("v1.0"),
    VERSION_1_1("v1.1"),
    VERSION_1_2("v1.2"),
    VERSION_1_3("v1.3");
    companion object {
        fun fromString(versionString: String): ApiVersion =
            try { entries.associateBy(ApiVersion::version).getValue(versionString) }
            catch (e: Exception) { throw InvalidApiVersion("Invalid path: $versionString - is not a valid or supported api version.") }
    }
}

object ApiVersionSerializer : KSerializer<ApiVersion> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ApiVersion", PrimitiveKind.STRING)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ApiVersion =
        ApiVersion.fromString(decoder.decodeString())

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ApiVersion) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.version)
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access the route with an invalid version (for example: `articles/v1.88`) I get the `BadRequestException` from ktor instead of the custom exception `InvalidApiVersion`.

**Why is it?**

Because of some REST spec, I need to return `404 NotFound` for an invalid API version instead of `400 BadRequest`, one way to achieve this would be to catch the `BadRequestException` in the StatusPages handler and return 404, but the problem is that I don't wanna convert all BadRequest to 404.

**It would be nice if I get `InvalidApiVersion` instead of `BadRequestException` for this particular case. Is there any way to achieve this?**

**Update:**

@aleksei-tirman answer solves the problem in the above code, but in some cause, the custom exception could be much deeper, what I mean is instead of `cause?.cause` you might need to do `cause?.cause?.cause?.cause` to get the actual root exception.
I might be wrong here but the below function works!

```kotlin
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<BadRequestException> { call, cause ->
        val root = getRootCause(cause)
        if (root is InvalidApiVersion) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, root.message)
        } else {
            throw cause
        }
    }
}
fun getRootCause(exception: Throwable): Throwable {
    var rootCause: Throwable = exception
    for (depth in 1 until 50) { rootCause.cause?.let { rootCause = it } ?: break }
    return rootCause
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cause of the `BadRequestException` is the `InvalidApiVersion`, you can check for that in the exception handler of the `StatusPages` plugin:

```
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<BadRequestException> { call, cause ->
        if (cause.cause is InvalidApiVersion) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, cause.cause?.message!!)
        } else {
            throw cause
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sometimes, I get the custom exception only at the first request failure, but in the subsequent retry I get the bad request again with the message `Can't transform call to resource` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: alright, I updated my question with a possible solution